# make AndroidGameView transparent

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, opentk

I have AndroidGameView, and I want to make it transparent so View behind it could be seen in parts where OpenTk draw transparent textures. I have found some examples with GLSurfaceView but I couldn't make it work the same. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In the `AndroidGameView` initialization do this:

```
SetZOrderOnTop(true);
Holder.SetFormat(Format.Transparent);
```

After that the view will be transparent and you can see anything you have under it.

Comment: Thanks Sami, We found a solution, as you can see in our code ;)